# Can I build/deploy wlapp and adapters via ant in MobileFirst 8

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

We created an ant script for MobileFirst 7 and executed the script via jenkins to create an automated deployment process.

Tutorial for creating an ant script in MobileFirst 7:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_buld_deploy_adapters.html
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_buld_deploy_apps.html

We are migrating to MobileFirst 8, so we want to automate our build and deployment process also, I haven't found a tutorial on how to create an ant script for building and deploying the wlapp and adapter files for MobileFirst 8. I'm not also sure if it's possible to create and ant script for MobileFirst 8.

This is what I only found on MobileFirst 8 ant task, I'm not sure if waht I'm looking for is alaso here, but its seems that its not there.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_installwladmin_reference.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With MFP 8.0, there are no more .wlapps. There is only application registrations.

Adapters are now built using CLI or maven. So you can plug that into your DevOps process. More details here:

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/creating-adapters/#build-and-deploy-adapters